# Make relative url get request with HTTP_Request2

Tags: php, relative-url, http-request2

On the client side I have a get request called by `$.get` with jQuery

> "modify_user.php?uid=SomeUserId"

with this `XMLHttpRequest`, I get some userID and load the form.
The problem is that in the client side I do not have my user id, in case I want to modify my user.

So I create another php file called

> modify_my_user.php

and basically what I wanted to do was get the id in the server side and simulate a request from server, like it was an Ajax request.

Something like this

```
require_once 'HTTP/Request2.php';


$r = new HTTP_Request2('Ajax/modify_user.php?uid='.$_SESSION['uid'], HTTP_Request2::METHOD_GET);
$r->setHeader(array('X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest'));
$r->send();

echo json_encode($r->getBody());
```

this is because in the modify_user I have a reject method if the request isn't a `XMLHttpRequest`

```
(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) === 'xmlhttprequest');
```

the thing is, when I try to make the get request from server(in modify_my_user.php) I'm getting this error

> HTTP_Request2_LogicException: HTTP_Request2 needs an absolute HTTP(S)
>   request URL, 'localhostWeb/Ajax/modify_user.php?uid=17' given in

Is there a way to enable relatives url with this package?

Comment: the relative call would be for you to use php without using HTTP_Request2

Comment: sorry, but I don't get you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot make HTTP requests without a host - never and nowhere.

There are several solutions to your problem:

1. If no uid is given to `modify_user.php`, simply use the one from the session automatically.
2. In case the special uid "current_user" is given to `modify_user.php`, the one from the session is used instead
3. Prepend `$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]` to your URL before requesting it.

Comment: Thanks! I solved it with the third option - cannot use the first one because was another case when no uid given